# How to set Text Color to all radio buttons from all radio groups in Java

Tags: java, android, loops, for-loop, onclicklistener

I'm trying to set the text color red, to all radio buttons but from all radio groups that I have. When is use `answer[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);` this is applied only to the last radio group.

If try to change the background color to all radio buttons with `radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` I get the following error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.RadioGroup.getChildAt(int)' on a null object reference`.

How can i fix this? Is there any other method to do that?
Here is my code:

```
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup[4];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        int i = 0;
        radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                String answers_log = " " + an.getAnswer();
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(answers_log);
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }

    finishButton = new Button(this);
    linearLayout.addView(finishButton);

    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < answer.length; j++) {
                    answer[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe its easier to use styles, anyway i cant see the line where you call getChildAt()

Comment: Thanks, but i need it dynamically.

Comment: no code about setTextColor?

Comment: You can dynamically apply the style...

Comment: Ur logic is Strange. Have u seen the View in phone?

Comment: @Nanoc The code `radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);` is exactly after the `answer[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);`
What can i dynamically apply the style?
@tinysunlight , I have seen on my emulator.
The task is very simple, i have 4 questions, and 4 answer for each question. I want when someone clicks the button, to set all the radio groups `clearCheck()` and all the radio button, the red color, not only the last one.

Comment: when (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) == false ,u add no button.U must just get only 1 answer for each.

Comment: @tinysunlight Does this screen shot help you?[link](http://gogo.ro/1.png)

Comment: use radioGroup[i].getChildCount() as the condition for the loop

Comment: @Nanoc thanks. walkmn has already found the issue.

Comment: I see, my comment was correct but late...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Try this code:

```
    radioGroup = new RadioGroup[4];
    answer = new RadioButton[4];
    int i = 0;
    for (Question qn : questions) {
        radioGroup[i] = new RadioGroup(this);
        radioGroup[i].setOrientation(RadioGroup.VERTICAL);
        int j = 0;
        for (Answer an : answers) {
            if (qn.getID() == an.getQuestion_id_answer()) {
                String answers_log = " " + an.getAnswer();
                answer[j] = new RadioButton(this);
                answer[j].setText(answers_log);
                radioGroup[i].addView(answer[j]);
                j++;
            }
        }
        linearLayout.addView(radioGroup[i]);
        i++;
    }

    finishButton = new Button(this);
    linearLayout.addView(finishButton);

    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < radioGroup[i].getChildCount(); j++) {
                    radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: If i use `radioGroup[i].length;` i get this error: `cannot resolve symbol 'lenght'`

Comment: paste `radioGroup[i].getChildCount()` instead  `radioGroup[i].length`, and move `int i = 0;` to before `for (Question qn : questions)` like in my updated post.

Comment: It worked man, thank you very much!!! This problem was annoying me for almost 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            radioGroup[i].clearCheck();
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
                radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setEnabled(true);
                ((RadioButton)radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
                ((RadioButton)radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j)).setChecked(false);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Same error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RadioGroup.clearCheck()' on a null object reference`

Answer (score -1):

I'm amazing!

U just want to get 4 `RadioGroup` and 4 `RadioButton`?

change `for(b: bs )` to `for(int i = 0;i<bs.size();i++)`

```
    finishButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        try{
            for (int i = 0; i < radioGroup.length; i++) {
                int len = radioGroup[i].getChildCount();
                for (int j = 0; j < len; j++) {
                    radioGroup[i].getChildAt(j).setBackgroundColor(
                            Color.GREEN);
                }
            }
         }catch(Throwable e){
          }

        }
    });
```

Comment: Same error: `Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.widget.RadioGroup.getChildCount()' on a null object reference`

Comment: Use answer[i].setTextColor(Color.RED)! And  sreenshot plz

Comment: i want to know the number of Question  and Answer

Comment: This is the code with your specification: [link](http://gogo.ro/1.png) This is the error: [link](http://gogo.ro/2.png) The emulator error: [link](http://gogo.ro/3.png) When i try this: [link](http://gogo.ro/4.png) look at the result: [link](http://gogo.ro/5.png) All i want is to have all radio buttons green background, not only the last 4, which are nested in the last radio group.

Comment: just try catch ! try to debug and watch the RadioGroup[4].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94100/discussion-between-alex-m-and-tiny-sunlight).

Comment: No error this time, but same result. Only the last 4 radio buttons from the last radio group get the green background [link](http://gogo.ro/5.png)